# Simple MVC error flow

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP MVC 4.0 and would like to understand the basics of custom validation. In this particular case, the model is not at all strongly typed with the controller or view so I need something different.

What I'd like to do is accept a new username on signup to my service, look in the database, and re-present the original form with a message if that username is taken.

This is my input form:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>New account</h2>

<form action= "@Url.Action("submitNew", "AccountNew")" method="post">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input id="password" name="password" type="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm Password:</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input id="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" type="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and here is my controller method upon submit:

```
    public ActionResult submitNew()
        {
            SomeService service = (SomeService)Session["SomeService"];

            string username = Request["email"];
            string password = Request["password"];

            bool success = service.guestRegistration(username, password);

            return View();
        }
```

If success is false, I'd just like to re-present the form with a message indicating so. I'm missing the basics of this error flow. Would you please help? thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're totally missing the point about MVC. You're supposed to be actually using Models for something like this. The models, then, can have the validation right on them to better be able to send it back to the page.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* add a ViewBag item

```
bool success = service.guestRegistration(username, password);
if (!success)
{
  ViewBag.Error = "Name taken..."
}
return View();
```

But you *should* create a view model...

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public string UserName {get; set;}
  //...other properties
}
```

...strongly type your view and use the built in html helpers...

```
@model ViewModel
//...
@using BeginForm("SubmitNew", "AccountNew", FormMethod.Post)()
{
  //...
  <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)</div>
  <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)</div>
  <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)</div>
}
```

...and leverage ModelState in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SubmitNew(ViewModel viewModel)
 {
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
       SomeService service = (SomeService)Session["SomeService"];
       bool success = service.guestRegistration(viewModel.username, viewModel.password);
       if (success)
       {
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "Name taken...")"
       return View(viewModel);
     }
 }
```

...or even write your own validator and just decorate your model property, eliminating the need to check success in the controller.